# To find the size of the memory obtained using malloc

Tags: malloc, sizeof

char buf[50];
   char* ptr;

scanf("%s", buf);
ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(buf)+1);

//And this, how to know that dynamic allocation is correctly done?
i want to know size of memory pointed by ptr

Answer (score 0):

Standard malloc function does not provide this information. 
This is no easy way to know the size of an object pointed by a pointer unless you use custom allocators or add some metadata to keep the size information along with the heap objects(when malloc is called memory is allocated from the heap layout) by interposing the malloc function.
There are solutions to provide this information. There is an idea named fat pointer and several fat pointer libraries can be found like [Cello](http://libcello.org/learn/a-fat-pointer-library). An improved version of the fat pointer can found in this [work](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2892212).